# Create instance of a generic type that takes a parameter a secondary generic type

Tags: c#, generics, abstract

I have an abstract class called Factory

The factory has a method createModel()

```
public abstract class Factory<T, U>{

    public T CreateModel(IDictionary<String, Object> parametersDictionary)
        {
            T toReturn;

            if (ValidateDictionary(parametersDictionary) != true)
                 return null;
            else
            {
                 toReturn = new T(U);
            }


            return toReturn;
        }}
```

In the else statement, I want to create a Car instance taking a CarPart object which I would get from another method call. This logic would be applied on other Factory subtypes so I want to inherit this method. The issue is I can't create the Car generic instance with another Generic parameter.

I looked around and found that I could use the Activator class.

> (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(
>   Car), args);

This however seems to work only when you have a certain type that you want to give to the constructor.

I also tried to do:

> public abstract class Factory where T: new()

But that didn't let me parse any argument to the constructor.

How can I implement this abstract class?

Edit1: changed the naming for clarification

Edit2: For clarification, U is a structure that contains aproximatelly 20 parameters necessary for creating T. So in order to create a new T, I need to pass it a U object that encapsulates all 20 parameters necessary.

Comment: What is `T`? I can only see type-definition for `Car` and `CarPart`. I assume `T` should be `Car`.

Comment: question is not clear also, if you need Factory then give it only CarPart input, and inside CreateModel resolve what object do you want to return - Factory should decide for you what it should return.

Comment: Can you show `Car`s constructor? Btw.: i think you´re confues on the type-parameters names. I suggest you to use `T` and `U` for the generic parameter in your factory-class definition and than things might get clearer as currently `Car` seems to be both - the name of the generic parameter and the name of an existing class.

Comment: where does the `CarPart` come from that you would like to pass into the constructor of `Car` ?

Comment: I apologise for the confusion. I originally named them T and U and then changed them to Car and CarPart. I changed everything back to use only T and U.

Comment: Why can't you just use `(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);`?

Comment: Because the args is expected to be of a specific type, while my U is a generic type. At least thats what I understood from the compiler error it gave.

Comment: Post the error, because I don't think you are understanding it correctly. `Activator.CreateInstance` is more than capable of taking a generic object as an argument. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/39A0NW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Abion47 pointed out that Activator.CreateInstance shouldn't have any issues doing what I need it to do I looked a bit more into the issue and made it work.

For anyone that might come across this:

```
public abstract class Sentinel<T,U> where T: new() where U: new() 
{
    public T CreateModel(IDictionary<String, Object> parametersDictionary)
    {
        T toReturn ;

        if (ValidateDictionary(parametersDictionary) != true)
            return default(T);
        else
        {
            U parameters = ParseDictionaryToParameters(parametersDictionary);
            toReturn = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] {parameters});
        }

        //If we got this far then everything should be fine.
        return toReturn;
    }

    public abstract U ParseDictionaryToParameters(IDictionary<String, Object> parametersDictionary);

    public abstract Boolean ValidateDictionary(IDictionary<String, Object> parametersDictionary);
}
```